# After deploying to heroku

Tags: django, git, reactjs, heroku

I have a webapp which is **not yet complete** but I recently deployed it to heroku. It uses:

- Django
- Rest-framework
- Reactjs

Now, I have deployed `deploy-heroku` branch of my project to `master` of heroku.

The only difference between my project's `master` branch and `deploy-heroku` branch is that I have made additional changes in `settings.py` (adding prostgre sql settings and all) in the `deploy-heroku` branch.

I want to add more features to my webapp so should I work on `master` and later copy-paste those changes to `deploy-heroku`. This seems redundant !! Is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What's wrong with this post?

Comment: Why would you copy and paste? That entirely defeats the purpose of git. Merge or rebase.

Comment: If I merge `deploy-heroku` with `master`, then I wouldn't be able to `localhost`.  That's why I write my new features in `master`, test them using `localhost`, then have to make those changes in `deploy-heroku` branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just let Heroku automatic deploy on master and use a ".env" file with Django-environ (https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) to change your settings.py. You should be able to create a local Django setting and a Heroku prod setting.

Example :

.env :

```
DEBUG=on
SECRET_KEY=your-secret-key
DATABASE_URL=psql://urser:un-githubbedpassword@127.0.0.1:8458/database
SQLITE_URL=sqlite:///my-local-sqlite.db
```

setting.py:

```
 import environ
    env = environ.Env(
        # set casting, default value
        DEBUG=(bool, False)
    )
    # reading .env file
    environ.Env.read_env()

    # False if not in os.environ
    DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

    # Raises django's ImproperlyConfigured exception if SECRET_KEY not in os.environ
    SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

    # Parse database connection url strings like psql://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8458/db
DATABASES = {
    # read os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] and raises ImproperlyConfigured exception if not found
    'default': env.db(),
    # read os.environ['SQLITE_URL']
    'extra': env.db('SQLITE_URL', default='sqlite:////tmp/my-tmp-sqlite.db')
}
```

Don't forget to add the .env file to your .gitignore and to update your Heroku environment variables in your **app -> settings -> Reveal config vars**

Comment: So if its on heroku, its will use postgresql but if its in my PC, it uses local db. right?

Comment: Any documentation on how to write an env file?

Comment: An `.env` file is a poor solution for Heroku. (a) Your database credentials and other sensitive settings are now in a tracked file. (b) `.env` files _entire purpose_ is to simplify the population of environment variables, which [Heroku supports natively](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). These files are useful _in development_, but you should be using proper environment variables via `heroku config` or the Heroku web interface on Heroku. (c) If the `.env` file is added to `.gitignore` as you suggest it won't ever make it to Heroku (which uses Git for deployment).

Comment: Indeed it's a poor solution if you want to use it for Heroku but the main goal here, if I well understand,  is to separate local environment and heroku environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge branches.

[Here is a good explanation of how it works](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)

Comment: `master` branch hosts locally and `deploy-heroku` has settings related to `heroku`.  So, if I merge these branches wouldn't there be a problem !

Comment: Dont commit changes on the local, let the project use heroku on master.
You should have 2 different settings saved and then optionaly choose which one you want to use.